# What does Stripe use for storage on backend?

Tags: database, api, stripe-payments

I notice Stripe uses a database that formats keys/IDs as `ch_15aCcp2eZvKYlo2CYmE3Fy2h` where "ch_" seems to be a prefix of the table name, or the type of Object that is being stored.

What database does this style of ids?  Might be custom but I've seen other API providers use similar style ids.

This is purely for my own curiosity.

Answer (score 6):

I don't work at stripe but take a lot of interest in their work. Some research has revealed that the keys (well the charge object keys which you are referring to at least) are randomly generated by their application code. See [this Quora post](http://www.quora.com/How-does-Stripe-generate-object-ids) from Patrick Collison.

In relation to databases: Judging by [this blog post](https://stripe.com/blog/announcing-mosql), I would estimate that they primarily use PostgreSQL with a growing amount of MongoDB usage. For instance, their open source Gaps tool uses MongoDB for data persistence. Sorry I can't post the link here, limited to 2 links per post for now. You can find it on github though.

Answer (score 3):

According to Patrick Collison in his [interview on Techzing](https://techzinglive.com/page/939/168-tz-interview-patrick-collison-stripe), Stripe uses MySQL and Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Redis should be included in the list, as for Brandur's blog, an engineer at Stripe https://brandur.org/redis-cluster.

Also a lot of content about Postgres in his blog.

Comment: redis is in almost every's stack but question is on primary storage backend not some caching stuff. the main database that is churning all the payments

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the underlying database technology but you can create similar unique ids with [nanoid](https://github.com/ai/nanoid).

Answer (score 0):

I believe their primary database is mongodb and secondary is postgresql; or simply combination of both. I think they stream data from mongodb to postgresql for sql-focused analytics

this was why they even created the old project https://github.com/stripe-archive/mosql, which explains above

Also one of the current engineers at stripe writes so much about postgresql/mongodb

> The API would happily pass it through and persist it to Mongo forever.

source: https://brandur.org/text#s3ripe